# Insert HTML in Div with a substr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to insert an underline or blank space in a div that is being affected with a keyup function. The objective is to be able to move where the blank space is in the text. The keyup function works fine, the inserting of the blank space (div class underline) isnt.

HTML:

```
<div class="bigwhitecard" id="bigwhitecard"></div>

<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type your card here" name="text"></textarea>
```

Javascript/Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#text').keyup(function(){
  $('#bigwhitecard').html($(this).val());
});

var blankplace = 0;

$('#rightbtn').click(function() {
blankplace++;
});

$('#leftbtn').click(function() {
blankplace--;
});

var b = '<div class="underline"></div>';

$('#bigwhitecard').each(function() {
var blankplace = 0;

var txt = $(this).text();
if (txt.length>0) {
    $(this).html(''+txt.substring(0,blankplace)+'<div class="underline">       </div>');
}
});

 });
```

Comment: Can you further expand on: "The objective is to be able to move where the blank space is in the text." What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: I plan on having the user be able to select where they want the blank space to be within the text.

Answer (score 0):

So use a substr to get the remaining text length that is left over and add it after the text.

```js
var filler = "__________";
var out = document.getElementById("bigwhitecard");
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var txt = this.value,
      placeholder = txt.length<filler.length ? '<span class="underline">' + filler.substr(0,filler.length-txt.length) + '</span>' : '';
  out.innerHTML = txt + placeholder;
});
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div class="bigwhitecard" id="bigwhitecard"></div>
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type your card here" name="text"></textarea>
```

And based on your comment

```js
var out = document.getElementById("bigwhitecard");
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("keyup", function() {
  var txt = this.value,
      ind = 6,
      len = this.value.length,
      pre = len > ind ? txt.substr(0,ind) : txt,
      suf = len > ind ? txt.substr(ind) : "";
  out.innerHTML = pre + "<span>_</sapn>" + suf;
});
```

```css
.underline {
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

```html
<div class="bigwhitecard" id="bigwhitecard"></div>
<textarea id="text" placeholder="Type your card here" name="text"></textarea>
```

Comment: This would be sort of the right idea except it will be a requirement that the blank space stay there, not get eaten up by text.

Comment: So the blank spaces just move??? So that split the string up at x and Y and put it there.       text.substr(0,X) + blank + text.substr(X)

Comment: basically, yes. the idea is for the user to preview in real time where the blank space will be in the text